# AAA authentication - Explanation of how each AAA command works

Tags: aaa

How asset authentication is handled for configuration sample presented below.

```
aaa new-model
    aaa authentication login console local group TACACS+
    aaa authentication login default group TACACS+ local
    aaa authentication enable default enable group TACACS+
```

Comment: I have no idea what you’re trying to ask.  Please rephrase.

Comment: I need an explanation of what each of the three lines does.

Comment: Okay. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

The line `aaa authentication login console local group TACACS+` is telling any protocol using “console” as the authentication group (list of servers to authenticate against) to use local authentication first and TACACS+ as the secondary authentication method.

The line `aaa authentication login default group TACACS+ local` is telling any protocol using “default” as the authentication group to use TACACS+ as the primary authentication method and LOCAL as the secondary authentication method.

The line `aaa authentication enable default enable group TACACS+` is saying that the enable password to access privileged mode is the local enable password first and the user TACACS password secondarily.

Comment: "default" is the only system defined (global) policy. "console" would simply be a user designated policy that applies where ever it's explicitly used. I define a "no_auth" policy for the system console. (device is physically secure; I want access on the console no matter what.) Remote access lines use different policies for different RADIUS/TACACS+ groups.

Comment: Also, the order matters... "local group..." checks the local db first. "group ... local" checks the group first, and falls back to local. Likewise the enable policy is "enable group..." so the local enable password is valid. (IME, every build does something different, so your mileage *will* vary.)

Comment: @Ricky Good catch. I didn’t notice the placement of the word console being after the word local.

Comment: @Ricky Yep.  That’s why I said which one it will use first and second.

Comment: @Ricky Man, all of these edits are what I get for trying to submit an answer while at a stop light instead of paying more attention.